# Why is only one of spark jobs running using only one executor?

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Spark cluster has 1 master and 2 workers. Application reads csv files from s3 to DataFrames, registers them as temporary tables and using sqlContext runs sql queries to create new DataFrames. Then these DFs are stored to MySql DB. These jobs are all running on multiple nodes.

But when I read these tables from DB back to DataFrames, register them as temp tables and run sqlContext query, all of the processing is done by only one node. What could be causing this?

Here is an example of my code:

```
 DataFrame a = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(options)
                .load("s3://s3bucket/a/part*");
 DataFrame b = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(options)
                .load("s3://s3bucket/b/part*");

a.registerTempTable("a");
b.registerTempTable("b");

DataFrame c = sqlContext.sql("SELECT  a.name, b.name from   a join b on  a.id = b.a_id");

c.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "c", prop);

// other jobs are similar 

Map<String, String> dOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
dOptions.put("driver", MYSQL_DRIVER);
dOptions.put("url", MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL);

dOptions.put("dbtable", "(select * from c) AS c");
rC= sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(dOptions).load();
rC.cache();

 dOptions.put("dbtable", "(select * from d) AS d");
 rD= sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(dOptions).load();
 rD.cache();

 dOptions.put("dbtable", "(select * from f) AS f");
 rF= sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(dOptions).load();
 rF.cache();

 rC.registerTempTable("rC");
 rD.registerTempTable("rD");
 rF.registerTempTable("rF");

DataFrame result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT  rC.name, rD.name, rF.date  from rC join rD on rC.name = rD.name join rF on rC.date = rF.date");

result.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "result_table", prop);
```

Comment: What are you using to submit your job ? When you mean "one node", do you mean that you can see only one worker on the master UI ?

Comment: @Hawknight I'm using spark-submit to submit job. Here is full command: "spark-submit --class MyClass --deploy-mode cluster s3://bucket/file.jar". I'm monitornia via Ganglia as well as Spark UI. Both recognize workers and I see that some jobs do execute in paralel. However, during job I've posted above, paralelization halts and certain task (within stage) is carried out only by one worker node. Here is screenshot from Ganglia UI showing that. http://pokit.org/get/img/2a5bcd853b97aad2bc9e86a90c9b2733.png

Comment: Based solely on the code, it is quite hard to tell why only one worker would be working on certain stages. Can you try to pin point exactly at what stage and what task the problem arises ?

Comment: @Hawknight This is information I've gathered from SparkUI. 
job 18: stage 17/25, task (for all stages 1036/2438), task 198/200 (in stage) and task 199/200
This is only for first time it occurs, I can update with next taks that stall, when they have. Here are some screenshots that might help you.
http://pokit.org/get/img/ba03e44c1e5d2c3bfa98f4f0db1f8021.png
http://pokit.org/get/img/89611aae56ba2cd6f1cf2aa4cfc2bfc6.png
http://pokit.org/get/img/689ec7cbf496f0876aa3ea32d3649131.png
If you find this information irelelvant, please specify what exactly you need, and I will provide those.

Comment: Ok it is a bit clearer now. Can you manage to find exactly which `jdbc` stage is problematic in your code ? Is it the first one with the `c` DataFrame or the last one with the `result` DataFrame ? Is your SparkConf specific for this job or shared globally with other jobs that execute on both of the nodes ?

Comment: @Hawknight It's last one, `result` DataFrame. SparkConf is not specific, it's the same for every node.

Comment: I would avise you to thorougly look at the output of your spark-submit and to try and understand how Spark is distributing your job, there may be hints in the numerous logs that can help you pinpoint why only one executor is used at a particular stage (look for `WARNING` log messages). As a last resort, you could try setting up a [Thrift server](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server) and reproduce your environment to see if it too only does it on one executor or not, but there might be a lot of configuration involved.

Comment: @Hawknight Here are all `WARNINGS` and `ERRORS` I found in log files: 
WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
WARN executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: An unknown (ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.xx-xxxx-x.compute.internal:34766) driver disconnected.
ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

Comment: It certainly looks like there is a problem happening, however it seems that the driver wasn't registered into Spark.. I can't say for sure that the issue comes from there, I haven't found anything related on the net. If the issue is solely based on the data, you can look into the partitioning of your DataFrame. You could try something as follow on your last query : `result.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("rC.name").jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "result_table", prop);` This is a long shot however ! You can also append `.explained` to the end of your sql query to see the physical plan

Comment: @Hawknight here is my physical plan: http://pastebin.com/j5CTqWxv

Answer (score 1):

Could you share with us your SparkConf() object?

A SparkConf() object contains the configuration for a Spark application. It is used to set various Spark parameters as key-value pairs such as:

-the master

-number of executors

-number of executors cores

-heap memory allocated

-other..

Comment: Here i my SparkConf Object:
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.spark.SchemaTransformer").setMaster("yarn-cluster");
Execution enviroonment:
spark.master = yarn
executor.cores = 4
executor.memory = 5120M

Comment: I think you miss some arguments. Try to add following methods. Something like:

SparkConf().set("master","yarn")\
        .set("spark.submit.deployMode" ,"cluster")
        .set("spark.executor.instances","8")\
        .set("spark.executor.cores","4")\
        .set("spark.executor.memory","5120M")\
        .set("spark.driver.memory","5120M")\
        .set("spark.yarn.memoryOverhead","10000M")\
        .set("spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead","10000M")

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify either {partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions} or {predicates} Spark will use a single executor and create a single non-empty partition. All data will be processed using a single transaction